# nodeJs cannot PUT

Tags: node.js, put

I am trying to make a PUT call to edit my database and render to my main page(catalog) after the database has been updated.

i use the following function

```
app.put('/catalog/tax/', tax.collect, tax.edit, tax.respond);
```

And the respond function is the following

```
respond: function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/catalog');
   }
```

The data gets updated but after that i get an error:

**"cannot PUT /catalog"**

It works perfectly fine if i use a POST call instead to add a row to the database.

Comment: the POST call is via the call:   app.post('/catalog/tax/', tax.collect, tax.add, tax.respond);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and only way I got the solution was after finding a typo in my put request address
instead of requesting to `"/api/courses/1"`, i was requesting to  `"/app/courses/1"`

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are using expressjs, You do not need to use .put for edits. Just use .post to make your edit.